# Which versions of IE use standard event model?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, dom-events

I've googled this but can't find a satisfactory answer. Which versions of Internet explorer, if any, implement the W3C DOM level 2 event model?

Comment: only IE9 will - see http://www.davidflanagan.com/2010/03/ie9-will-have-a.html IE6/7/8 don't

Comment: @cryo the link is broken

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE 9 should be the first IE version to add the W3C event model in addition to their proprietary model [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Microsoft-specific_model).

Further reading:

- [IEBlog: DOM Level 3 Events support in IE9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/dom-level-3-events-support-in-ie9) (March, 2010)
- [Robert Nyman: Internet Explorer 8 – Fix Event Handling, Or Don’t Release It](https://robertnyman.com/2008/11/04/internet-explorer-8-fix-event-handling-or-dont-release-it/) (November 2008)

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks guys. I have been writing pure jQuery for about a year now and wanted to go back and fill in all the gaps in my knowledge about vanilla javascript. Events being one of those gaps.

Answer (score 2):

I think no browser does completely at the moment.

An excellent resource on which event is implemented in what browser is the [quirksmode.org compatibility table.](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html)

Also read the [introduction to events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) on the same site.

Answer (score 2):

> Microsoft does not follow the W3C model up until Internet Explorer 8, as their own model was created prior to the ratification of the W3C standard. Internet Explorer 9 is supposed to follow DOM level 3 events.

That's what can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events).